# Creating TeX file from RMarkdown without LaTeX installed on PC

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

This maybe a duplicate but couldn't find the question here.

For some reason I cannot have LaTeX installed on my PC. I am hoping to run my .Rmd code and generating .tex file (using keeptex true in YAML) which I can use on another PC to generate pdf.

I haven't tried this yet but would this work?

Comment: Yes, it would, but make sure to copy the full set of output files, because the .tex file may contain references to external files such as figures. That said, @Baroque's suggestion below may be an easier way to go.

Comment: @YihuiXie Thanks a lot. Yeah I did think about the figures and was already thinking that moving the files had to be done carefully such that the references in. tex file doesn't get disturbed.

Comment: Couldn't you create a folder that has all the .Rmd and other files, generate the `.tex` inside the same directory, and then just copy over the folder that contains everything, also keep in mind if the other PC doesn't have your required latex packages, if need be.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried installing/using the tinytex package?

```
install.packages(tinytex)
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

https://yihui.org/tinytex/

This will allow you to create PDFs from LaTeX without having a full LaTeX installation

Comment: Thanks. This sounds interesting. Will try sure. But my question still remains about whether I can generate only the TeX file.